# Would incense burn at a different rate if oriented differently?

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life

This is motivated by [this question in the Puzzling.SE beta](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1959/candle-timing-measurement) about measuring 90 minutes of time using two candles that burn for one hour. (Feel free to read up on that before I spoil the puzzle!)

The solution given was to light one of the candles on both ends by holding it horizontally, but as one user mentioned, the candle's burning rate would be significantly affected by its orientation. This reminded me that I have heard of this puzzle before but using sticks of incense instead of candles. Does that actually improve the rigour of the puzzle though? How would the burn rate of incense be affected by the incense's orientation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incense is a much better object for this puzzle than a candle. When a candle burns, the wax is melted. Normally the melting wax has to travel up the wick before it burns, and that gives a relatively constant rate of burning.

When you place the candle horizontally (or upside down), some of the melting wax can fall away without burning. Consequently the flame travels much more quickly, and the candle will burn a lot faster.

By contrast, the incense does not melt, so the above mechanism does not apply and the burn rate is less dependent on orientation.

I wonder if it's coincidence that the puzzle (to which the answer is "[burn the candle at both ends](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/burn+the+candle+at+both+ends)") was an interview question for a software company...

Answer (score 1):

Incense burning is much more of a smoldering reaction. You've got a porous medium that retains heat well and admits oxygen poorly.  The propagation is mostly limited by the ability of heat to conduct along the stick and the ability of gases to pass in and out of the solid structure.  Conduction doesn't care about gravity and The viscosity in those small pores will significantly counteract buoyancy on the gases (probably to the point of being negligible).  So yes incense makes the problem more rigorous in that gravity will play much less of a role.

The caveat here is that you do have gas flow outside of the stick itself.  This will create a stream of warm gases that could pre-heat the fuel and accelerate the pyrolysis reaction.  Burning down would probably be slowest, up fastest and sideways in between.